# Google Analytics API limits exceeded, even with new user and site ID

Tags: php, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I'm using the PHP *gapi* library to pull data from GA. Last night, I exceeded the user daily limit for requests for one of my GA users. Today, I'm running the same script with both a different user AND a different site ID, and I'm still getting the same error from GAPI:

> 'GAPI: Failed to request report data. Error:
>   "usageLimitsuserRateLimitExceededUnregUser Rate Limit Exceeded. Please
>   sign uphttps://code.google.com/apis/console"'

I am using standard username/password authentication to connect FYI.

Similar to the first user, this second user has access to GA and has also enabled the GA API in the Google APIs Console. The second user, though, has made no recent successful requests. Any idea why I would be receiving this error for this totally different user?

Thanks.

Comment: You might want to have a look at this: https://code.google.com/p/gapi-google-analytics-php-interface/issues/detail?id=78

Comment: Thanks for the link, it helped me solve the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're receiving that error because you have not associated your requests with the project you created in the APIs console.

Since you're using username/password and not OAuth 2.0 for authentication (which will automatically identify your requests), you need to include an API Key with your requests. The API Key will associate your requests with the project you registered in the APIs Console which will then enable you to get full quota. Right now your requests are unregistered, which have very low quota and is the reason you're getting the rate limit error for unregistered requests.

1. Get the API Key from the APIs Console for the project you registered.
2. Add it to every request you make to the Google Analytics API.

For example, in PHP you do this using **setDeveloperKey**:

```
$client->setDeveloperKey('YOUR API KEY);  // Sets the API key for the client.
```

There are a lot of resources that talk about this: [What is a Key](https://developers.google.com/console/help/?csw=1#WhatIsKey), [Analytics Limits and Quotas](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/limits-quotas), [Analytics Error Responses](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/coreErrors)

Comment: Thanks, that solved the problem. Specifically, I added `$parameters['key'] = '....';` after `$parameters = array('ids'=>'ga:' . $report_id);` in gapi.class.php. FYI, the link mentioned above by Thomas Orozco was where I obtained the specific syntax to use.

Comment: I tried this, but its not working in function protected function authenticateUser($email, $password)
$post_variables = array(
   'accountType' => 'GOOGLE',
   'Email' => $email,
   'Passwd' => $password,
   'setDeveloperKey'=>'abcdogjdsighsklghksdkgj',
   'source' => gapi::interface_name,
   'service' => 'analytics'
  );